# WooCommerce - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: woocommerce

I'm trying to install WooCommerce, but when I try to activate it, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. I've tried installing it via the Plugin Search in the admin panel, and FTP, but both result in the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below options here:

1) editing Your .htaccess File

php_value upload_max_filesize 1000M
php_value post_max_size 2000M
php_value memory_limit 3000M
php_value max_execution_time 1800
php_value max_input_time 180

2) Using a Plugin:https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maximum-execution-time-exceeded/

3) http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/php/update-local-php-settings

I think one of above will help you.

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-internal-server-error-in-wordpress/
this link will help you